# Compress SASS output based on JEKYLL_ENV?

Tags: css, sass, jekyll, minify

I have a static site setup with Jekyll. I'm compiling multiple SCSS files into a single `style.css` output file.

In local development, I'd like this file to be expanded so as to make it easier to debug. In production, I'd like this file to be minified.

It seems that the only way to set the SASS compiler to do minification is to hardcode the value into `_config.yml`.

Is there a way for me to vary the SASS compilation output style based on `JEKYLL_ENV`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an additional config file to override the `compressed` style on development with the `--config` option, and ignore it on production (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options).

`_config.yml`:

```
sass:
  style: compressed
```

`_config-dev.yml`:

```
sass:
  style: expanded
```

`sass.style` can be `nested`, `compact`, `expanded` or `compressed`.

---

**Development**:

```
bundle exec jekyll serve --config _config.yml,_config-dev.yml
```

Since the dev file is last, its options overwrite the default.

---

**Production**:

```
bundle exec jekyll build
```

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know that config files could be stacked.